# Symmetric functions and roots of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-functions

$f = x^3-\frac{1}{2}x^2+1$ and their roots $a,b,c$. I want to find polynomial of degree 3 with roots $a^4,b^4,c^4$. 
I know that i need express $e_i(a^4,b^4,c^4)$ in terms of $e_i(a,b,c)$ those coefficients of f. But if i do it directly it will be time-consumming process. Is there much easier way?

Comment: What is $e_i$??

Comment: Elementary symmetric polynomial $e_i = \sum_{j_1<\dots<j_i}x_{j_1}\dots x_{j_i}$

Comment: I remember doing something of this sort in my first year UG, using $a+b+c+d = -(-1/2), ab+bc+..+ac=0, abc=-1$ in this case!

Comment: Yes, i know, and i can calculate $e_i(a^4,b^4,c^4)$. But it's really hard to express $e_2(a^4,b^4,c^4)$. May be there is much easier ways..

Comment: Maybe by using $\sum\limits_{cyc}$ notation or by doing $(a,b,c)\rightarrow(a^2,b^2,c^2)$ two times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing $(a,b,c)→(a^2,b^2,c^2)$ two times is clearly the easier way.
Let $A=a+b+c,B=ab+bc+ca,C=abc$.
Consider $$\begin{align}&(x^{1/2}-a)(x^{1/2}-b)(x^{1/2}-c)\times
(x^{1/2}+a)(x^{1/2}+b)(x^{1/2}+c) = \\&(x^{3/2}-Ax+Bx^{1/2}-C)\times (x^{3/2}+Ax+Bx^{1/2}+C) = \\&(x^{3/2}+Bx^{1/2})^2 - (Ax+C)^2 = \\&x^3+2Bx^2+B^2x-A^2x^2-2ACx-C^2\end{align}$$
So, $(A,B,C)\rightarrow(2B-A^2,B^2-2AC,-C^2)$ does $(a,b,c)\rightarrow (a^2,b^2,c^2)$

Comment: Maybe is one way of doing things but I don't think you're sure that it's the easier way

Comment: @Elaqqad: Yup, not the easiest-for-sure, as one need to think hard for at least 5-10 minutes in order to produce this, while computing $e_i(a,b,c)$ manually would be faster and more straightforward and consuming nearly comparable amount of time and power. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the power of the **Dandelin-Gräffe iteration**. For any polynomial $p$ with roots $z_i$, the polynomial $p^{(1)}(x)$ defined via
$$
p^{(1)}(x^2)=p(x)·p(-x)
$$
has the same degree as $p$ and roots $z_i^2$. Repeating this process, the polynomial $p^{(2)}(x)$ defined via
$$
p^{(2)}(x^2)=p^{(1)}(x)·p^{(1)}(-x)
$$
has still the same degree as $p$ and roots $z_i^4$.

---

For the given polynomial $f(x)=x(x^2)−\frac12x^2+1$, this iteration gives
\begin{alignat}{4}
p^{(1)}(x)&=(−\tfrac12x+1)^2 - x(x)^2&&=-x^3+\tfrac14x^2+x+1
&&=-x(x^2+1)+1+\tfrac14 x^2\\
p^{(2)}(x)&=(1+\tfrac14 x)^2 - x(x+1)^2&&=-x^3-\tfrac{31}{16}x^2-\tfrac12x+1
\end{alignat}

Answer (score 1):

One way is the following:
$$\begin{align}(x-a^4)(x-b^4)(x-c^4)&=x^3-\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} t^4\right)x^2+\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^4\right)x-1\tag 1\\
&=x^3-\frac12\left(\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} t^3\right)-1\right)x^2 +\frac12\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)^2\right)x-1\tag2\\
&=x^3-\frac12\left(\frac12\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} t^2\right)-4\right)x^2 +\frac{1}2x-1\tag4\\
&=x^3-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-4\right)x^2+\frac12x-1\tag 5\end{align}
$$

---

- Move from $(0)$ to $(1)$ $abc=-1$ and $\sum_{cyc}(xy)^4=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(xyz)^4}{z^4}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{t^4}$
- Move from $(1)$ to $(2)$ used $t^4=\frac{1}{2}t^3-t$ and $\frac{1}{t^4}=\frac{1}{2t^2}-\frac{1}{t}$ avec $\sum_{cyc}t=\frac12$ and $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{t}=\frac{ab+bc+ac}{abc}=0$
- Move from $(2)$ to $(4)$ use $t^3=\frac{1}{2}t^2-1$ and note that $ab+bc+ac=0$ so the sum $\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{t^2}$ is :
  $$(ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2=\underbrace{(ab+bc+ac)^2}_{=0}-2abc\underbrace{(a+b+c)}_{=\frac{1}{2}}=1$$
- Move from $(4)$ to $(5)$ note that $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$ ($ab+bc+ac=0$)